# Generate Instagram related Hashtags - API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, hashtag, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to generate multiple related hashtags based on the keyword entered by the user. For example: if the user has typed 'meme', it would generate multiples hashtags related to it (memes, funny memes)

I looked for an Instagram API but didn't find any such endpoints. There are lots of sites and apps available over this thing. Can anyone suggest to me how this would work? I'm not expecting you to do work for me. Just need your guidance on this? Is there any way to achieve this?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/ (I goes over all the endpoint but didn't find it, is there any other way to achieve it?)

Demo:- https://toolzu.com/hashtag-generator-for-instagram/ (this brings related hashtags, difficulty and number of times each hashtag has been used)

Comment: Update: I found an unofficial Instagram API to fetch related hashtags

Comment: Can you put up the link here? I am also looking for such api.

Answer (score 0):

This api returns hashtags related to a keyword. It's easy to use with axios. Downside is a the limited number of free calls

hashtag api: https://rapidapi.com/miguel.aka.kelter/api/hashtagy-generate-hashtags/

Good luck